# Error C2057: expected constant expression in vs2008

Tags: c

```
static const unsigned int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };  
static const int q = sizeof(x) **/** sizeof(x[0]);  

size_t fun(int n, int m)  
{  
    unsigned int p[q];  
}
```

How do I solve this error? It is a c code.

Comment: `unsigned int p[sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])];`  or `#define q (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))` instead of `static const int q = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

what is this `**/** sizeof(x[0]);` , this isn't how to make a comment,and don't forget to put semicolon at the end of the expression.

```
static const unsigned int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };  

static const int q = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]); /* sizeof(x[0]); */

size_t fun(int n, int m)  
{  
    unsigned int p[q];  
}

int main()
{
}
```